# Graphviz does not display SVG images

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to create a Graphviz chart with an SVG image embedded in a node, but the SVG image does not display whereas using a PNG image works fine. For example, I download [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Test.svg) test image, and then use the following code

```
digraph G {
  a [label=<<TABLE><TR><TD><IMG SRC="/full/path/Test.svg"/></TD></TR></TABLE>>];
  a -> b;
}
```

Executing

```
dot graph.gv -Tpdf -o graph.pdf
```

Produces a PDF with a empty spot where `Test.svg` should be. Graphviz does not report any error message. I am doing this on macOS with Graphviz 2.40.1 installed via Homebrew. I have had no better luck on Windows 7, although on Windows Graphviz reports an error, `Warning: No loadimage plugin for "svg:cairo`,

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours banging away on this problem on OS X High Sierra. Finally got it working. I had to install graphviz using option `--with-librsvg`:

`$ brew install graphviz --with-librsvg --with-app --with-pango`

Comment: I get `invalid option: --with-librsvg` on OSX Mojave

Comment: Possible fixes here but none worked for me: https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/issues/33

Comment: brew no longer allows all those options I don't think. :(